# Function to get top k words in a given String

Tags: java, strings, heap

This is a two-part job:

1. to identify a word
2. to find the top `k` words

I've tried to use regex to split but it's taking 10x more time when string is really long. The top `k` strings are found using a priority queue. I've created a `min` priority queue for first `k` element, if the frequency of the next word is greater than the `min` element. I then remove `min` and insert the new word.

```
 public static List<String> getTopStrings(String input, int k)
        {
            if(k<0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value k cannot be negative for top k elements: k= "+k);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(input==null || input.isEmpty() || k==0)
            {
                return list;
            }
            Set<Character> separators = new HashSet<Character>();
            separators.add(' ');
            separators.add(',');
            separators.add('.');
            separators.add(';');
            separators.add(':');
            separators.add('"');
            separators.add('(');
            separators.add(')');
            separators.add('-');
            separators.add('/');
            separators.add('\\');
            separators.add('\'');
            separators.add('?');
            separators.add('\n');
            separators.add('\r');
            separators.add('!');
            separators.add('|');
            separators.add('~');
            separators.add('\'');
            separators.add('[');
            separators.add(']');
            separators.add('{');
            separators.add('}');
            separators.add('&');
            separators.add('%');
            separators.add('$');
            separators.add('#');
            separators.add('@');
            separators.add('*');
            separators.add('=');
            separators.add('+');
            separators.add('>');
            separators.add('<');

            final Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            int count, wordStart=0;
            for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
            {
                if(separators.contains(input.charAt(i)))
                {
                    addWord(input, wordMap,wordStart,i);
                    wordStart=i+1;
                }
            }
            addWord(input,wordMap,wordStart,input.length());
            List<String> keySet = new ArrayList<String>();
            keySet.addAll(wordMap.keySet());
            if(keySet.size()<=k){
                return keySet;
            }

            PriorityQueue<String> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<String>(k, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return (wordMap.get(o1)-wordMap.get(o2));
                }
            });

            for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            {
                minHeap.add(keySet.get(i));
            }
            for(int i=k;i<keySet.size();i++)
            {
                String key = keySet.get(i);
                count = wordMap.get(key);
                if(count>wordMap.get(minHeap.peek()))
                {
                    minHeap.poll();
                    minHeap.add(key);
                }
            }
            list.addAll(minHeap);
            return list;
        }
        public static void addWord(String input, Map<String, Integer> wordMap, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            int count = 0;
            String word = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex).toLowerCase();
            if(word!=null && !word.isEmpty())
            {
                if(wordMap.containsKey(word))
                {
                    count = wordMap.get(word);
                }
                wordMap.put(word, count+1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Initialize Set with values**

Your method of initializing the hashset with values takes quite a bit of space. I would create a static field:

```
public static final String[] SEPARATORS = new String[] { " ", ",", ".", ";" };
```

And then use it like this:

```
public static final Set<String> separatorsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(SEPARATORS));
```

**Extract code to methods**

Your `getTopStrings` method currently does three things: extract words from string, count amount of duplicate words, sort the result of that by frequency. I would at least create separate methods for the first two and the third functionality.

**Simplify Sorting**

Your sorting mechanism using a queue seems overly complicated. If you are using Java 8, it could be reduced to three lines (or one really long one):

```
    // sort by value, reversed
    Stream<Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = wordMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((x,y) -> (y < x) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1))); // alternatively: use reversed and cast
    // flatten map to list:
    List<String> collected = sorted.map(entry -> entry.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    // top k:
    List<String> topK = collected.subList(0, k);
```

**Misc**

- in Java, it is customary to place curly brackets on the same line as the opening statements.
- use curly brackets even for one line statements for improved readability and to avoid future bugs.
- use more spaces, eg around `==`, `<`, `+`, after `;`, etc for increased readability.
- declare variables in as small a scope as possible to increase readability.

Comment: The reason the OP is using a priority queue is to  keep the running time limited to n * log(k). Sorting the entire list and picking the first k element will run in n * log(n). Seeing how they've emphasized that the strings can be very long, it's safe to assume n can be large enough to make a significant difference.

Comment: What's this about `comparingByValue((x,y) -> y - x)`? It's ugly, it's buggy and it's wrong. What's wrong with [`Comparator.reversed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--)? Although beware of [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137421/failure-to-infer-type-at-an-unexpected-place-possible-javac-bug).

Comment: @BoristheSpider how is it buggy? And reversed did not work for me because of incompatible types. But with a cast as mentioned in your link it works. thanks.

Comment: @tim `Integer` overflow.

Comment: Can it be done in O(n) time ?

Answer (score 5):

Well the disadvantage of regex is, that if written wrong you'll have a bad time. The next disadvantage of regex is, you will have to keep a large String in memory.

But regex has two strong advantages:

1. There is character-classes. You can use these to define what you want to recognize as word.
2. Java Matchers are inherently "iterative".

This makes it rather simple to create a short method that gets all words from a String:
<sub>(sidenote: I'm using a strong oversimplification for the Pattern. For more information on Java Regexes, read the ["manual"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html))</sub>

```
private static final Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w++)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

//method header
    Matcher words = WORD_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (words.find()) {
        final String nextWord = words.group();
        // do something with your found word
    }
}
```

Now since that is a simple way to grab all "words" in a String the only thing left is to count how often a certain word appeared, but you seem to have already accomplished that, so I'll leave that in your hands ;)

Comment: I agree. But, for really long string, its taking too much time. (10x)